# Replacing an item in an object?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm looping through an object:

```
foreach ($data as $asset) {

    $asset->test = 'test';
}
```

test exists in $data and is set to something else, I wish to replace it with 'test'.

The above fails to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Simply `$data->test = 'something else';`. (provided `test` is public)

Answer (score 1):

You should use referenced loop with `&` like `foreach ($data as &$asset)`

```
foreach ($data as &$asset) 
{
    $asset->test = 'test';
}
```

Referenced loop will have an effect to `$data`, otherwise only current `$asset` object changes.

Comment: That is not needed if `$data` would be an array of objects as objects are never copied. Though this is not relevant as the OT wants to change the property `test` of the object `$data`. Simply `$data->test = 'test';` would suffice. No `foreach` is necessary.

Comment: @Yoshi if `test` index is belong to `$data`, yes you right `$data->test = 'test';`. But if belong to `sub item`, have to loop

Comment: Of course, though I think the OT just used the loop because he/she didn't know any better.

Comment: I used `foreach loop` because of questioner use `$asset->test` that is  `sub item`. You know that not referenced array doest any effect. I just show the this trick the questioner :)

Comment: Maybe, but read the question: *"test exists in $data and is set to something else, I wish to replace it with 'test'."* The loop is just a mistake.

Comment: According to this sentence, you right! :) I thought that questioner want to modify array sub items

Answer (score 0):

You can think about using a function that already exists, like array_walk that would execute your function.

```
function test_exists(&$asset) {
    $asset->test = "test";
}

array_walk($data, "test_exists");
```